# Не могу считать файл в Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

```
var inputStream: InputStream = File("app/src/main/assets/Kotlin1.in").inputStream();
var lineList = mutableListOf<String>()
inputStream.bufferedReader().useLines { lines -> lines.forEach { lineList.add(it) } }
```

FileNotFoundException

Comment: Неправильно указан путь. В чем вопрос?

Comment: Я нажимаю на текстовый документ и там копирую Path как он может бытьь не правильным?

Comment: Очень просто он может быть неправильным. Или вы не верите сообщению об ошибке? Достаточно вставить этот адрес в файловый менеджер, и убедиться, что адрес неверный.

Comment: D:\ProjectInAndroid\app\src\main\assets\Kotlin1.txt полный пас а всеравно выдает ошибку

Comment: Я не могу даже до файла достучаться и я даже не знаю почему

Comment: Вот что пишет E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.translate, PID: 5708
    java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:503)

Comment: AndroidRuntime работает в своей виртуальной машине. Почему вы решили что там есть диск D и какие-то папки на нем? Там вообще-то Linux.

Answer (score 0):

Поток для чтения `assets` открывается в Андроиде вот так:

```
val inputStream = context.assets.open("Kotlin1.in")
```

Все что нужно, это доступ к контексту: активити или приложения.